# Threads in ExecutorService not completing

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, producer-consumer

I have a producer-consumer pattern. 1 producer (that does some work) and 7 consumers (on a 8 core machine). A producer is meant to download 7 files at a time (out of 2000) and wait for 7 threads to process them, before moving on to the next 7. The setup is roughly as follows:

```
            ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

        int pollWait = 4; 
        int queSize = 7;
        Broker broker = new Broker(queSize,pollWait);
```

Broker implements a LinkedBlockingQueue with capacity of 7.

```
        Producer producer = new Producer(); 
        producer.setBroker(broker);
        Future<Integer> producerStatus = threadPool.submit(producer);

        int numConsumerThreads = 7;

        ArrayList<Future<Integer>> consumers = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>();

        for(int c=0; c < numConsumerThreads;c++)
        {
            String threadName = "consumer-"+(c+1);
            Consumer consumer = new Consumer(threadName);
            consumer.setBroker(broker);

            Future<Integer> consumerStatus = threadPool.submit(consumer);
            consumers.add(consumerStatus);                            
        }   

        if(producerStatus.isDone())
        {
            Integer numFilesRead = producerStatus.get();
            System.out.println("[INFO] Total number of files downloaded by producer: " + numFilesRead);
        }

        int k=0,numIndexedByThread=0;
        while(!consumers.isEmpty())
        {
            final Iterator<Future<Integer>> i = consumers.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext())
            {                   
               Future<Integer> f = i.next();
               if (f.isDone())
               {
                  i.remove();
                  numIndexedByThread = f.get();
                  k += numIndexedByThread;
               } 
             }
        }
        System.out.println("[INFO] Total number of files indexed: " + k);
        threadPool.shutdown();
```

The problem I am seeing is the program does not execute.

Comment: you have too much code and narrative here for 99% of the readers to wade through. make this the minimal amount of code of just what you are having problems with and you might get more accurate responses.

Comment: The get on the Broker can return NULL if the underlying BlockingQueue.poll() does not return within 4 minutes.  Have you tried using a BlockingQueue.take() instead?

Comment: Yes Jose. I have tried take() and I am checking against NULL.

Comment: This is an interesting problem.  Would you be able to post the output?

Answer (score 1):

#### You have serialized the processing of the results

The following line blocks and serializes the entire processing of the results:

```
Integer numConsumedByThread = consumerStatus.get();
```

The correct idiom is to check each one `isDone()` and only call `.get()` when `isDone()` returns true, otherwise the `.get()` blocks the loop until it has a result to return.

#### Pseudocodeish

```
while(!listOfFutures.isEmpty())
{
    final Iterator<Future> i = listofFutures.iterator;
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
       Future f = i.next();
       if (f.isDone())
       {
          i.remove();
          // call .get() and process the completed result 
       } 
     }
}
```

Read the JavaDocs for [`Future.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get())

Comment: Hi Jarrod. I can see that being a problem downstream. The problem is even before that. I implemented your suggestion but the producer still fills up the broker to its limit and the program hangs. The same (3 step) behavior inside the consumer print statement holds as i wrote above.

Comment: Reduce the code in your question to just what you are having a problem with then, there is too much noise in it right now, I doubt many people will take the time to wade through it as it is now, much less see what you are having problems with. That said, you still have a serialization issue that my answer fixes.

Comment: fair point. I edited the original question to the essence (I think).